# Error-1054 Unknown column 'column name' in 'field-list'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When I create one **trigger** of *before insert* for prevent wrong input then trigger has created but after insert values in that table then it create error like **Error-1054 Unknown column 'column-name' in 'field-list'**. I want to create trigger for prevent wrong input from users then how is it possible that insert values in table after creating trigger. Code shown as below of trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mobile_no` BEFORE INSERT ON `invoiceform_clients` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if length(clientPhonenumber)=10 THEN 
 insert into invoiceform_clients(clientPhonenumber) values(clientPhonenumber); 
ELSE 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Mobile NO. must be in 10 digit'; 
end if; 
END;
```

Comment: you need to use `new.clientPhonenumber` in the if condition and also the insert statement in the trigger is invoking the same table and it does not make sense, you should only check error and return `SIGNAL`

Comment: Please show your table structure here

Comment: create table invoiceform_clients{ clientID  int(10)  NO  PRI  NULL auto_increment
userID  varchar(10)  NO   NULL 
clientNr  varchar(25)  NO   NULL 
clientCompany  varchar(50)  NO   NULL 
clientFullname  varchar(50)  NO   NULL 
clientAddress2  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
clientAddress1  varchar(255)  NO   NULL 
clientCity  varchar(25)  NO   NULL 
clientState  varchar(15)  NO   NULL 
clientZipcode  int(6)  NO   NULL 
clientEmailaddress  varchar(50)  NO   NULL 
clientPhonenumber  int(10)  NO   NULL 
clientFaxnumber  varchar(15)  NO   NULL

Comment: But right now it shows error like "Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger" after use new.clientPhonenumber instead of clientPhonenumber

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer below. I've edited it to add a suitable trigger body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the insert statement inside the trigger body - just validate the column value and throw the signal if it's wrong. If the trigger code exits normally, the original `INSERT` which fired the trigger will succeed as well.

You should also be testing `NEW.clientPhonenumber` instead of just `clientPhonenumber` - this specifies that you want to check the field in the record *as it will exist after the `INSERT` completes.*

The trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mobile_no`
  BEFORE INSERT ON `invoiceform_clients`
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF length(NEW.clientPhonenumber) != 10 THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Mobile NO. must be in 10 digit'; 
  END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: I have one web form that is uploaded on webserver if I want to prevent wrong input from user then this database can handle wrong input.That means connect webform to database that is already have trigger